# Redirecting packages when migrating PPAs

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad

I have some packages in a PPA and, now, have created a group PPA. Is there a way to put in a redirect such that anyone installing package `foo` from `ppa:jrhacker/ppa` can be redirected to `ppa:initech/ppa` but package `bar` from `ppa:jrhacker/ppa` is left alone?

I don't particularly care if the redirect is an error message telling them the correct migration path. As I see it, I have two options:

1. Always copy the packages from `initech/ppa` back to `jrhacker/ppa`.
2. Create a dummy package in `jrhacker/ppa` that, when it runs, spits out an error message with the installation instructions when the program is invoked.

I'd like something a bit more elegant than either of these two. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

The dummy package would work. As would deleting `foo` from the PPA, so that nobody can install the old version. Then change the description of the PPA to point the user at the new PPA.